# Getting an error: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined when trying to post to a Slack bot hosted on Heroku

Tags: node.js, axios, bots, slack-api, dotenv

I am attempting to develop and launch a Slack bot using this [repo](https://github.com/slackapi/template-actionable-notifications). I haven't made any customizations other than deploying on Heroku.

I have everything set up and I believe to be operating as it should be, however, when I go to post a request to my app, I get the following error: `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined`.

**Here is the full error log:**

```
2020-01-24T20:44:59.024897+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/incoming" host=bot-name.herokuapp.com request_id=e5367452-5894-434d-b7e7-15c024480cf0 fwd="34.223.105.71" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=35ms status=400 bytes=235 protocol=https
2020-01-24T20:51:31.327412+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
2020-01-24T20:51:31.327426+00:00 app[web.1]:     at validateString (internal/validators.js:112:11)
2020-01-24T20:51:31.327428+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Url.parse (url.js:155:3)
2020-01-24T20:51:31.327431+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:150:13)
2020-01-24T20:51:31.327433+00:00 app[web.1]:     at dispatchHttpRequest (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:67:22)
2020-01-24T20:51:31.327436+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2020-01-24T20:51:31.327438+00:00 app[web.1]:     at httpAdapter (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:20:10)
2020-01-24T20:51:31.327440+00:00 app[web.1]:     at dispatchRequest (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:59:10)
2020-01-24T20:51:31.327442+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5) {
2020-01-24T20:51:31.327444+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
2020-01-24T20:51:31.327447+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

I do not understand what the error means/what the program wants. Should I be passing over some other url in the payload?

**Here is the section of the app that handles this part:**

```
app.post('/incoming', (req, res) => {
  debug('an incoming ticket was received');
  Ticket.fromExternal(req.body)
    .then((ticket) => ticket.postToChannel())
    .then(() => {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
      debug(`an error occurred creating the ticket: ${error.message}`);
      res.status(400).send('The ticket was not created');
    });
});
```

I am happy to provide more information where needed but I am lost here and not sure what is needed to resolve this or more likely, what I am doing wrong. As you can likely tell, this is all new to me.

This is the response I get from my HTTP Post:

```
{
    "response": {
        "status_code": 400,
        "headers": {
            "server": "Cowboy",
            "connection": "close",
            "x-powered-by": "Express",
            "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
            "content-length": "26",
            "etag": "W/\"1a-vV63UJ4QvBHXPkXtRjN8HhDrha0\"",
            "date": "Fri, 24 Jan 2020 21:07:50 GMT",
            "via": "1.1 vegur"
        },
        "body": "The ticket was not created"
    }
}
```

I am using a third party SAAS platform to send the POST request. It is Tray.io.

Here is the payload I am sending over. Not sure what if anything I am missing. The ticket information is the generic message detailed in the repo.

```
{
    "body": {
        "raw": "{\n  \"id\": \"1234\",\n  \"link\": \"https://somehelpdesk.localhost\",\n  \"title\": \"Test ticket\",\n  \"description\": \"Oh no! Something went wrong and now everything is on fire :fire:\",\n  \"requester\": \"Leia\",\n  \"status\": \"Open\",\n  \"agent\": \"Chewy\",\n  \"priority\": \"High\"\n}"
    },
    "queries": [],
    "headers": [
        {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/json"
        }
    ],
    "auth": {},
    "follow_redirect": false,
    "parse_response": "true",
    "url": "https://membership-slack-bot.herokuapp.com/incoming",
    "reject_unauthorized": true,
    "tls": {}
}
```

Comment: Hi Dakota, can we see the axios post request you are making on the client side?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I updated the bottom of my message with more information on the post I am sending over. @HenryLy